# "rails new react-app --webpack=react" not adding "packs" folder in app/javascript directory

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack, crud

I am trying to learn to create a basic CRUD web application using Ruby on Rails and React.js. I was following the steps in this webpage https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-react-ruby-on-rails/ when I realised that the command "rails new react-app --webpack=react" is not creating the "packs" folder in my app's directory. I am using Ruby version 3.0.0p0, and Rails 7.0.4.

This is how the folder looks like on my computer:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr9PY.png)

I tried reinstalling ruby, rails, webpacker and everything but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Even I started to learn with the same tutorial and faced the same issue.

What I came across is that, in Rails version 7 and above. They changed the way we deal with JavaScript.

Because of it now they aren't using JSX at all. Some other library called as htm is introduced by DHH to use. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k73LKxim6tw

So if you want to use React with Rails 7,

You can do by -

1. Import maps (the new Rails 7 default)
2. Separate frontend app that talks by Rails API
3. Using a JavaScript bundler